# Cambiar color solo un textview en un Adapter

Tags: android

Hola tengo un recyclerview adaltado (con un adapter). Dentro de este adapter le puedo cambiar de color a todo el recyclerview  segun sea par o impar, pero lo que quiero, que ademas tambien cambie un solo texview que esta dentro de ese recyclerview de color.

```
  @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull EncuentroAdapter.ViewHolderencuentro holder, int position) {

    final TablaPartidos tablaPartidos = ListPartidos.get(position);

    nombrelocal.setText(String.valueOf(tablaPartidos.getNombreld()));
    resulocal.setText(String.valueOf(tablaPartidos.getResultadold()));
    nombrevisitante.setText(String.valueOf(tablaPartidos.getNombrevd()));
    resuvisitante.setText(String.valueOf(tablaPartidos.getResultadovd()));
    fecha.setText(String.valueOf(tablaPartidos.getFechad()));
    hora.setText(String.valueOf(tablaPartidos.getHorad()));
    campo.setText(String.valueOf(tablaPartidos.getCampod()));
    terminado.setText(String.valueOf(tablaPartidos.getTerminadod()));

    if (position % 2 == 0) { holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#81ecec")); }
    else { holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#00cec9")); }

    if (tablaPartidos.getTerminadod().equals("S")) {
        // Aqui es donde quiero cambiar de color solo a este textview
    }

    holder.nombreencuentro.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            onEncuentroClickListener.onEncuentroClick(tablaPartidos);
        }
    });
}
```

Gracias

Comment: `tutextview.setTextColor();` y da igual que esté en un recyclerView, en un layout o donde sea. Si eres capaz de acceder al elemento textView, solo tienes que ejecutar la función.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar el método `setTextColor()` definiendo un color Hexadecimal, RGB o un color definido en `colors.xml`,

ejemplos:

```
if (tablaPartidos.getTerminadod().equals("S")) {
    //Cambia a color verde.
    holder.textView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#00FF00"));
}
```

---

```
if (tablaPartidos.getTerminadod().equals("S")) {
    //Cambia a color verde.
    holder.textView.setTextColor(Color.argb(0,0,255,0));
}
```

---

Dentro de `colors.xml` define el color:

```
<color name="verde">#00FF00</color>
```

definelo a tu `TextView`:

```
if (tablaPartidos.getTerminadod().equals("S")) {
    //Cambia a color verde.
    holder.textView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.verde));
}
```

Comment: Es un `RecyclerView`. Cuando la vista hace el Binding tiende a tomar vistas recicladas para crear una nueva, por ende, debe hacer una condición `else` que vuelva el textView a su color original. Si lo deja así, simplemente cuando haga scroll se crearan textviews reciclados que también tiene dicho color.